# Не получается объединить несколько фрагментов кода (Python)

Tags: python, база-данных, сокет, messenger

пишу мессенджер для школьного проекта, время уже очень сильно жмёт (осталось 15 часов до показа его руководителю проекта)
имеется 4 скрипта:
2 клиентских
2 серверных
нужно объединить серверный с серверным и клиентский с клиентским, чтобы их было по одному.
По отдельности они прекрасно работают
т.е. первый сервер с первым клиентом работают замечательно, так же как и второй сервер со вторым клиентом.
просто суть в том, что первая "пара" скриптов отвечает за регистрацию пользователей и работой с базой данных, а вторая "пара" отвечает за отправку сообщений (но уже без регистрации).
Как их объединить в два кода (1 клиентский и 1 серверный) я уже не знаю.. потратил уйму времени в попытках это сделать, но так и не вышло, вечно какие-то ошибки. в общем я в отчаянии, прошу помогите добрые люди...

это сервер 1:

```
import sqlite3
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

# Создаем соединение с базой данных SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Создаем таблицу пользователей, если она не существует
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    password TEXT NOT NULL
                )''')
conn.commit()

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        user_data = json.loads(post_data)

        if self.path == '/register':
            username = user_data.get('username')
            password = user_data.get('password')

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
            conn.commit()

            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("User registered successfully".encode())
        
        elif self.path == '/login':
            username = user_data.get('username')
            password = user_data.get('password')

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (username, password))
            user = cursor.fetchone()

            if user:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write("Login successful".encode())
            else:
                self.send_response(401)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write("Invalid credentials".encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), RequestHandler)
    print("Starting server on http://localhost:8000...")
    server.serve_forever()
```

клиент 1:

```
import requests


def send_request_to_database_login():
    # Вход пользователя
    login_data = {
        "username": input('Enter your name: '),
        "password": input('Enter your password: ')
    }

    login_response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/login", json=login_data)
    print(login_response.text)

def send_request_to_database_register():
    # Регистрация пользователя
    registration_data = {
        "username": input('Enter your name: '),
        "password": input('Enter your password: ')
    }

    register_response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/register", json=registration_data)
    print(register_response.text)

while True:
    choice = input('Enter 1 for Login, 2 for Register: ')

    if choice == "1":
        send_request_to_database_login()
    elif choice == "2":
        send_request_to_database_register()
```

сервер 2:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
# server's IP address
SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PORT = 5002 # port we want to use
separator_token = "<SEP>" # we will use this to separate the client name & message

# initialize list/set of all connected client's sockets
client_sockets = set()
# create a TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
# make the port as reusable port
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# bind the socket to the address we specified
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
# listen for upcoming connections
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

def listen_for_client(cs):
    """
    This function keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
    Whenever a message is received, broadcast it to all other connected clients
    """
    while True:
        try:
            # keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
            msg = cs.recv(1024).decode()
        except Exception as e:
            # client no longer connected
            # remove it from the set
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")
            client_sockets.remove(cs)
        else:
            # if we received a message, replace the <SEP> 
            # token with ": " for nice printing
            msg = msg.replace(separator_token, ": ")
        # iterate over all connected sockets
        for client_socket in client_sockets:
            # and send the message
            client_socket.send(msg.encode())


while True:
    # we keep listening for new connections all the time
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] {client_address} connected.")
    # add the new connected client to connected sockets
    client_sockets.add(client_socket)
    # start a new thread that listens for each client's messages
    t = Thread(target=listen_for_client, args=(client_socket,))
    # make the thread daemon so it ends whenever the main thread ends
    t.daemon = True
    # start the thread
    t.start()

# close client sockets
for cs in client_sockets:
    cs.close()
# close server socket
s.close()
```

клиент 2:

```
import socket
import random
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import Fore, init

# init colors
init()

# set the available colors
colors = [Fore.BLUE, Fore.CYAN, Fore.GREEN, Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX,
          Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX, Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX, Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX,
          Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX,
          Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.RED, Fore.WHITE, Fore.YELLOW]

# choose a random color for the client
client_color = random.choice(colors)

# server's IP address and port
SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT = 5002
separator_token = "<SEP>"

# initialize TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
print(f"[*] Connecting to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")
# connect to the server
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
print("[+] Connected.")
# prompt the client for a name
name = input("Enter your name: ")

def listen_for_messages():
    while True:
        message = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print("\n" + message)

# Make a thread that listens for messages to this client & print them
t = Thread(target=listen_for_messages)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    # Input the message you want to send to the server
    to_send = input('Enter message: ')
    # A way to exit the program
    if to_send.lower() == 'q':
        break
    # Add the datetime, name, and the color of the sender
    date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    to_send = f"{client_color}[{date_now}] {name}{separator_token}{to_send}{Fore.RESET}"
    # Finally, send the message
    s.send(to_send.encode())

# Close the socket
s.close()
```

Пробовал всеми способами, но увы..
надеюсь что кто-нибудь поможет
(OS Win10 x64, Python 3.11.5)